# Conversion from nullptr_t to type with implicit conversion from std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I've encountered the following situation that fails in several compilers but works in others.  I'm wondering if the code is valid or not according to the C++11 standard.  We have a type taking `std::function<void()>` as the sole argument constructor and try to make a `std::pair` containing it, passing `nullptr` as the argument for it's position in the `std::pair`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
  Foo(std::function<void ()> f = nullptr) { }
};

typedef std::pair< void*, Foo > TestPair;

int main(void) {
  Foo f(nullptr); // always works
  //f = nullptr;  // never works
  TestPair p1(nullptr, static_cast< std::function<void()> >(nullptr)); // works
  TestPair p2(nullptr, nullptr); // fails in some compilers
  return 0;
}
```

You can [test it here](https://godbolt.org/g/FejP74) with different compilers.  It compiles in VS 2015, GCC >= 6.1, and Clang >= 3.4.  It fails in the Clang bundled with XCode 8 (clang-800.0.42.1), Clang 3.3, and GCC 5.4.  Each gives some variation on:

```
candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'nullptr_t' to 'const Foo' for 2nd argument
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: Is this legal code according to the C++11 standard or not? i.e. is failing to compile a compiler bug or is compiling successfully a compiler bug?

Comment: all modern compilers (I don't know how modern is clang-800.0.42.1) compile this fine while older versions fail, so I eager to suppose it became valid recently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a conversion constructor which convert from nullptr_t to Foo :

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

struct Foo {
  Foo(std::function<void ()> f = nullptr) { }
  Foo(std::nullptr_t) {}
};

typedef std::pair< void*, Foo > TestPair;

int main(void) {
  Foo f(nullptr); // always works
  //f = nullptr;  // never works
  TestPair p1(nullptr, static_cast< std::function<void()> >(nullptr)); // works
  TestPair p2(nullptr, nullptr); // fails in some compilers
  return 0;
}
```

MSVC sometimes doesn't require a copy constructor for copy initialization.

---

```
Foo f = nullptr;
```

Without a proper conversion constructor, this will require two user defined conversion for implicit converting from std::nullptr_t to Foo (the compiler will not do this): from `std::nullptr_t` to `std::function<???>` and then to `Foo`. The first converting might work under c++17 for other circumstance, but not in this case.

---

The std::pair's constructor is forwarding nullptr to Foo's constructor, and something changed in the implementation of the standard library.

Sorry for the delay. I had a little adventure in the awesome error messsssssage and in the the source code of the standard library of GNU.

Here follows the forwarding constructor for std::pair in g++-6 and g++-5:

```
// source code from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pari.h
template<typename _U1, 
         typename _U2, 
         typename
  enable_if<
    _MoveConstructiblePair<_T1, _T2, _U1, _U2>() &&
      _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_T1, _T2, _U1, _U2>(),
    bool
  >::type=true>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
    : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }

template<typename _U1,
         typename _U2,
         typename
  enable_if<
    _MoveConstructiblePair<_T1, _T2, _U1, _U2>() &&
      !_ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_T1, _T2, _U1, _U2>(),
    bool
  >::type=false>
explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
    : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
```

---

```
// source code from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pari.h
template<class _U1,
         class _U2,
         class = typename
  enable_if<
    __and_<is_convertible<_U1, _T1>,is_convertible<_U2, _T2>>::value
  >::type>
constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
    : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
```

---

```
// error message from g++ 5.4
// This constructor failed us. 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:62,
                 from main.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:144:12: note: candidate: template<class _U1, class _U2, class> constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)
  constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
            ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:144:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_pair.h:141:38: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
       template<class _U1, class _U2, class = typename
```

The reason why g++-5 doesn't accept the code is because that `std::nullptr_t` and `Foo` isn't convertible.

g++-6's `_MoveConstructiblePair` is roughly something for telling whether we can construct an object from another object. And in this case, constructible.

Conclusion: the forwarding constructor of std::pair changed his requirement from **Convertible** to **MoveConstructible**.

Comment: I believe you are right about the two user-defined conversions.  In C++14, the `std::pair` constructors mostly changed to add `constexpr` and in VS 2015 they are defined this way while in XCode 8 they are not.  Can you explain the difference in terms of `constexpr`?

Comment: Nice answer.  VS 2015's implementation also has equivalent checks (using `is_constructible`).  Both VS and GCC seem to split into two declarations based on whether it's convertible or not, but then implement both versions the same.